# Wrong values in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I hope some of you are familiar with Tkinter in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import sys
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *

CDatei = subprocess.Popen("/home/pi/meinc++/Spi")
print("Hallo")

i = 0
x = 0
FunktionsWert = ""

def GetValue():
        with open("/home/pi/meinc++/BeispielDatei.txt","r") as Datei:
                for line in Datei:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    return line

def WithoutNull(input):
    ReturnValue = input
    while ReturnValue is None:
            ReturnValue = GetValue()
    return ReturnValue

def UebergabeWert():
    while x == 0:
        WholeString = WithoutNull(GetValue())
        StringVar, DatumVar = WholeString.strip().split(' - ')
        IntVar = [int(v) for v in StringVar.split()]
        print IntVar
        return IntVar

def UebergabeTkinter():
        x = UebergabeWert()
        print x
        x0 = x[0]
        return x0

def Warum():
        Variable.set(UebergabeTkinter())
        root.update()


try:
    root = Tk()
    Variable = IntVar()

    Label1 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable)
    Label1.pack()

    print "Hallo"
    root.after(1,Warum)
    root.mainloop()



except KeyboardInterrupt:
    CDatei.kill()
```

What my code basically does, is calling a C-programm with Popen. The C-programm then measures the values of different sensors and write it in a text-file. The Python-Code then reads the data from the text-file in (GetValue), then python checks if there's a Null-value (WithoutNull) and finally the programm splits the String (the format is: "val1 val2 val3 val4 - date") in values and timestamp (UebergabeWert)

Alright, so now i wanted to put everything in a Tkinter window and i looked through some Tutorials and found that i could update lables by using this...

```
def Tkinter():
            Variable.set(UebergabeTkinter())
            root.update()
try:
    root = Tk()
    Variable = IntVar()

    Label1 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable)
    Label1.pack()

    print "Hallo"
    root.after(1,Tkinter)
    root.mainloop()
```

Got it so far? Good. When i run this code the values are getting horrifyingly high&low (over 9000 instead of 800 and then suddenly drop to 0)

When i remove the root.update the values are fine but the label just updates 2 times. What is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The "prints" are just for me keeping track of the process

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but have you tried porting the C program to Python? [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) is instructions on how to build extensions with C or C++. Also, a popular drag-n'-drop form designer named [Page](http://page.sourceforge.net/) is easy to use and will more than likely help you organize front-end vs back-end.

Comment: Hi Noah, no I haven't tried that yet but to be honest, apart from the Tkinter, the communication over a textfile really works fine

Comment: I have some example code but I'm not certain if it's what you want. Are you constantly trying to read and update or just read once and draw once?

Comment: Well I'm sure your code could help me with the implementation of some other code of mine, so I'd be thankful if you'd share it. For this example however, I'd like to stick with the .txt-methode. I am constantly reading out data, about 50 times/second

Comment: Okay i figured out a bit, i replaced root.after(1,Tkinter) with Tkinter(). Now it works!

Comment: Don't use a `while` on Tkinter. Paused an GUI loop, most bad idea ! Additional : if 
 not using an internal loop,  you never need an update task.

Comment: What do you mean by "internal loop"?

Comment: Internal loop meaning not running a `while True` inside of the equivalent of `main`. You're going to want to multi-thread. Which isn't as complicated as it sounds. [Threads, Tkinter, and Asychronous I/O (Python)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/). Could also try [Combining Tkinter and Asynchronous I/O with Threads](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch09s07.html) Both articles use the same method but explain everything differently. I sincerely hope it helps you.@Quotenbanane